# Keep div loaded when navigating through Wordpress site. Ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress, html, load

I have a music player that I'd like to keep loaded when navigating through the site. It's a custom built Wordpress theme. I've tried multiple plugins, but nothing seems to be able to accomplish it. The div id is #stratus...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion could be to reload the page using AJAX. That is, do not refresh the page completely, just the content within certain divs. In this way, the page is never actually refreshed and the music player can keep running.